# Get Commit Files List on Bamboo

Tags: git, build, diff, bamboo

Does anyone know how to get list of files that were committed and got Bamboo CI server triggered? My aim is to get a list of changed files during build process and to validate them (PHPlint, validating twig files..) on Bamboo with custom scripts. Problem is that Bamboo always does "git clone", so searching git log can't help.

Comment: You can access last commit if you are writing a plugin. Then you can use it to get the changed files. I would recommend scanning all files again.

Comment: Bamboo has a tab with Commits (http://<BAMBOO_URL>/browse/<PROJECT>-<PLAN>-<BUILD_NUMBER>/commit  , one ugly way to do it (but it solves the problem), is catching them on this via some HttpClient. If you type on Javascript console: document.querySelector(".form-view .files"), it will return the "<ul>" that have all "<li>" that you need. Or (good way) you can discover where Bamboo puts that information and copy. *-*

Comment: Thank you. It was all pointing to something that way. Very strange that Bamboo is lacking such simple and needed option. Tnx for these solutions. More likely I'll parse commit tab.

Answer (score 1):

Crossposting an answer found on https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/Bamboo-Determine-git-commit-details-files-changed-before/qaq-p/483322

This requirement could be fulfilled by using Bamboo REST API:
/rest/api/latest/result/<bamboo.buildKey>/<bamboo.build.Number>?expand=changes.change.files

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry I wanted to comment but my reputation is too low). I think if you uncheck "Use shallow clones" on your repository options then you will get let's say a full clone with the history of your git repo. Then from a script task you will be able to do a git clone.

Good luck